# Strategies to narrow membership of clusters (exclude distant noisy observations)

Tags: r, clustering, noise

I have some empirical data that naturally consist of clustered observations (typically 2-3 clusters) plus some noise mostly between clusters.
In R we can simulate data e.g. like two clusters of normal distributed data plus some random noise:

```
set.seed(8)
data <- c(rnorm(1000, 1, 1), rnorm(500, 25, 3), runif(100, 5, 20))
```

Now this looks as

```
hist(data, 100)
```

[image]

Now I am really a novice in clustering but my goal is given data to identify the clusters (with K-mean clustering). What I am seeking is a strategy to narrow the number of members in clusters, effectively excluding what mostly is noise. One way I guess is iteratively to minimize variance within clusters by excluding outliers. However I am sure smarter strategies exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have noisy data, then I would strongly suggest using a clustering algorithm that can deal with noise, e.g., [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) (where the "N" actually stands for "noise"). It does not require you to specify the number of clusters in advance, does not require clusters to be spherical and will identify outliers, i.e., data that don't belong to *any* cluster, as noise.

In R, you can use the [`dbscan` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/index.html).

Comment: Thats great - I took a look at the algorithm in dbscan. It also features a membership probability which is probably something I could use.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is really well described by a *Gaussian*, then **Gaussian mixture modeling** is exactly what you are looking for, unless you have a lot of noise. When there is a lot of noise, you may need additional "clusters" for the noise only.

K-means doesn't support clusters with different *variance* well.

DBSCAN does not assume spherical or Gaussian clusters.